# Track Database table changes with Sails.js

Tags: sails.js

**My Goal:**
Then database table was **externally** changed, I want to send WebSocket notification to clients.

**Question:**
Is there a "native" Sails.js way to track changes in database table populated via Model?

Comment: The problem is how to catch model (e.g. database table) change event? The point is what table can change externally. Is I need periodically fetch table, compare from previous state and then, if it change, broadcast message? Or sails has more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

I only dabble in sails but I'm not aware of a way.  You might make a "model-listener" service that utilizes your adapter of choice's socket/channel capabilities.  You'll have to start the listeners at some point via a hook or in the bootstrap file.

The problem you're going to run into is determining if the event(create, update, drop/delete) was external or sails.  I'm more familiar with PGSQL and know you can provide an application name to your connection and could include it in your publish message so your listener/subscribe handler can ignore non-sails related events.

**PGSQL trigger/notify/listen**

- Event Triggers
- Notify
- Listen

**MongoDB**

- Capped Collections
- Tailable Cursors

---

Of course waterline supports more adapters than the two I've listed here but I tried to pick the two I assume are the most popular.  I know this might be the answer you had hoped for but it might give you some ideas to try.

Sorry, I'm a new poster so I'll try to provide some links in comments if it will stackoverflow will allow me.

Comment: Capped Collections and Tailable Cursors explained with an example (includes links to mogo docs for each concept) - http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.fr/2015/01/how-to-create-pubsub-application-with.html

Comment: PSQL Event Triggers [postgresql.org/docs/event-triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-triggers.html),  
PSQL Notify [postgresql.org/docs/sql-notify](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) PSQL Listen [postgresql.org/docs/sql-listen](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html) and Using the node-postgres module for notifications (same one waterline adapter uses) - [github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#notification--object-message](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#notification--object-message)